# Dead simple SSH tunnel for my Windows users

Tags: windows, ssh, tunnel

I'm running a Minecraft server, and many of my users are on a college campus whose network doesn't play nicely with Minecraft. I'm looking to package together a dead-simple way of creating a SSH tunnel to the server. Ideally, they would just double-click something to set it up. I'm prepared to do significantly more work on my end, if need be.

If there isn't anything simpler, I can just tell them to use PuTTY, but I'm afraid I might scare some of them away.

Comment: There is no policy forbidding connecting to Minecraft servers from this campus. As far as I know, the connection problems are a side effect of their overzealous anti-torrent measures.

Comment: Not sure why this is being voted to close as off-topic, as you're not asking for a pre-made product. Seems valid to me, a lack of research effort shown though. :/

Comment: The close vote was due to the question ostensibly violating the campus network's terms of use. The relevant comment has since been removed.

Comment: Ahhhhhh.. That makes sense.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundle PuTTY's `plink.exe` and a batch script that sets up the tunnel:

```
@plink -v -N -D 1234 user@host
```

Replace `-D 1234` with your desired tunnel options (`-D`, `-L`, `-R`; syntax same as in OpenSSH). (According to comments, you need `-L 25565:localhost:25565`.)

---

To avoid users having to answer the SSH key verification prompt:

1. export PuTTY's cached key to a `.reg` file:

   ```
   reg export HKCU\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys hostkey.reg
   ```
2. open `hostkey.reg` in Notepad;
3. in the file, *delete all other host keys* except your Minecraft tunnel host;
4. add `@reg import hostkey.reg` as the *first* line of your batch script.

Comment: So, a .bat file in plink.exe's directory containing `@plink -v -N -D 25565 miner@example.com` to connect localhost:25565 to example.com:25526?

Comment: -D is short for DynamicForward, also knows as a SOCKS Proxy, so you'd have to set up Minecraft to use a SOCKS proxy pointing to port 1234.  Like @grawity said, use a different tunnel option.  I'm assuming THEY will run the putty session (plink) so swap the '-D 1234' with this:  -L1234:localhost:1234  This will allow the client to connect to their own PC on port 1234, the tunnel will transfer the connection to the server and shove the data to localhost:1234 (from the point of view of the server, so itself).  Replace Mincraft's ports with 1234.

Comment: The above comment assumes that the minecraft server is running on your ssh server.  Otherwise, instead of 'localhost', use the IP of the Minecraft server.